# What happens when a tag is removed?

Tags: discussion, help-center

> What happens when a new tag is created?
>
> The new tag will now be available for all other community members to
>   use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in
>   the moderator tools new tag report.
>
> However, note that:
>
> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from
>   the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6
>   month period. meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag
>   on a question, are not allowed.

I saw this in [Helper Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

I'm curious about what happens when a tag is automatically removed.

1. Would those already tagged questions be untagged?
2. Could I still use this removed tag to search questions?

Comment: @RobertLongson #1 can arise if a tag is only ever present on a single question. #2 is still a moot point, though, as there's nothing else to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would those already tagged questions be untagged?

Yes, and when it was the only tag on that question the question gets the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag because it is mandatory for a question to have a tag. On [burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) it might happen that a bunch of questions end-up being in [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) but if it is a burninate request that is monitored by the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) we like to prevent this from happening or fix that soon after the event.

> Could I still use this removed tag to search questions?

Technically you can but is kind of useless as you will not find any questions, assuming none of the caches are stale. Shortly after removing a tag a search might return questions but under normal conditions this takes minutes to resolve.

If you're interested where a now removed tag was used you can query [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and look at the [posthistory table for types 3 and 6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) (initial tag, edited tags), like I did in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501983?tagname=once)